# Reading externally submitted form values into a webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is there any way to read form variables submitted from an external website to a .net form page?  I need to submit a username/password combination from an outside website to a c#.net form page and have the values automatically entered into the corresponding login fields (to be self-submitted via javascript).

From what I learned, which is minimal, the framework only reads form variables if IsPostBack is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Request.Form to access anything posted to that page. It doesn't have to be from an internal PostBack.

In your case, something like so would get you that value.

string user = Request.Form["Username"];

Comment: We had tried this but were getting empty values.  I'm learning this platform on the fly so my knowledge is extremely shallow.  Plus, this whole form page is built into ADFS so I'm sure there are other checks and validations in place that prevent cross-site scripting like this I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have the HTML form submit the form values to a "Generic Handler" (.ashx) and store those values either A) in a session state, or B) pass them to the web form (.aspx) page via query parameters (probably A if you're talking passwords).

Technically any asp.net page or handler can access the `Request.Form` properties, which should contain all the form variables from a request.  But it might get confused if the page also needs to handle it's own postback fields.

Also, if this is coming from another website (i.e. other domain) you can run into some problems with that.  There are mechanisms in place that are meant to mitigate cross-site scripting attacks and other related cross-site attacks, so you might run into those.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to modify, or even instantiate, .ashx files.  This is what happens when you don't get a proper tutorial beforehand -__-